# Fractional part to Int

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to return the Fractional part of a number as an Integer value.

How can I do it?

For example I have 12.98 and I want to return 98 in an Integer variable.

Comment: First subtract the current integer part (12) and then multiply what´s left (0.98) with 100.

Comment: It may be 12.369258714... !

Comment: It may be 12.00101 or 12.101 and both should be 101?

Comment: Been ages since I was in Delphi, but seem to recall that you can Fract which returns the fractional part, convert it to string, remove leading zero and decimal point then convert string to it. But as @SirRufo asks, is .00101 the same as .101?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: I don't want to use Frac function. I need this in an special situation. Yes , I want 101 in both example.

Comment: Do you know that 12.98 (exact value) doesn't exist in computer?

Comment: Why you don't want to use frac function? It is a special case or what? Otherwise, transform your float value into a string, delete everything which is before the '.', delete the zeros after the '.' and convert it to integer...

Comment: 12.98 was an example. maybe it is 12.12 or 1.64 or etc.

Comment: RBA : I use your solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
function FractionToInt(const Precision:Integer; const Amount: Double): Integer;
begin
  Result := Trunc(Frac(Amount) * Power(10, Precision));
end;
```

Comment: It's interesting that you accept this despite it not doing what you said you required. Look at your response to Sir Rufo's comment.

Comment: @Despatcher this function requires Round rather than Trunc because of the issue of non-representability in binary fp of many values with terminating decimal representation

Comment: @David. How does it not do what he requires? "I want to return fractional part as an integer". That's what it does. He does not ask to Round it, up or down. at "precision"= 2, 12.98 will return 98. So will 12.98989898.

Comment: Read the comment from Sir Rufo, and the answer. As for Trunc vs Round you have to understand representability. The closest double to 12.98 happens to be greater that 12.98. If it was less then your code would return 97.

Comment: I think for the purpose this splitting hairs. "If it was less then..." so 97 would be the correct answer or 979999.

Comment: [Comment Edit]: OK I just read all the comment under the question. especially "I want 101 in both examples(.00101 and .101)" why would you want that? I've done a lot of currency work including currencies where you have sum & round then adjust to nearest 0.25 (because that's the smallest coin in issue) I didn't appreciate he would want the wrong answer in some cases!

Answer (score 3):

The standard function `Frac` returns the fractional part of the number.

This function returns the value as a floating point value. You want the fractional part as an integer, using a decimal representation. But that's just not possible. Or at least will not do what you expect.

For example, what would you expect for 0.1? Well it turns out that 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.1

As another example, in double precision, your value of 12.98 is actually represented as

```
12.98000 00000 00000 42632 56414 56060 11152 26745 60546 875
```

which I am sure is not what you are expecting. So what you are asking for will, if interpreted at face value, not behave as you would expect. I think you will need to take a little time to come to terms with this issue of representability. Required reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you want to work with fractional values with decimal representation, you need to use a decimal rather than binary data type. In Delphi that would typically mean using the `Currency` data type which is a fixed point decimal data type.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. I need to write a currency number to word in Persian. I solve it by converting fractional part to string.

Comment: The solution is, as I said, to use a decimal representation rather than a binary representation.

Answer (score 3):

This will work up to 10 Decimal places

you will need to include math in the uses clause

```
function GetFractionValueAsInteger( Value : Double ) : Integer;
var fFracValue : Double;
    iFracLength : integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  fFracValue := Frac( value );
  if fFracValue > 0 then
    fFracValue := SimpleRoundTo( fFracValue + 0.00000000001, -10)
  else if fFracValue < 0 then
    fFracValue := SimpleRoundTo( fFracValue - 0.00000000001, -10);
  if fFracValue = 0 then
    exit;
  if fFracValue < 0 then
    iFracLength := Length(Floattostr( fFracValue ))-3
  else
    iFracLength := Length(Floattostr( fFracValue ))-2;
  if iFracLength <= 0 then
    exit;
  result := Round( fFracValue * Power( 10,  iFracLength));
end;
```

Example of using this

```
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 12.98 ) ) );         //=98
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 12.9 ) ) );          //=9
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 12.000 ) ) );        //=0
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( - 10.333 ) ) );      //=-333
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 33.33 ) ) );         //=33
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 33.000333 ) ) );     //=333
ShowMessage( inttostr( GetFractionValueAsInteger( 33.1023456789 ) ) ); //=1023456789
```

i have included SimpleRoundTo because sometimes getting the Frac value of 3.33 can return something like 0.332999999999998

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
const
  DECIMALS = 2;
var
  I: Real;
  Inte: Integer;
begin

  I := 12.98;
  Inte := StrToInt(Copy(FloatToStr(Frac(I)*100),1,DECIMALS));
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Inte));

end;
```

You need define your constant of decimals. Isn't the best solution, but i hope help you.

Comment: This won't do anything useful. It might work for 12.98, but imagine what happens when `FloatToStr(Frac(I)*100)` is 1.0.

Comment: Yes, for it i put the phrase: Isn't the best solution, but i hope help you. This answer is just for help a few the member because nobody has answered him.